# Handle mouseenter/mouseleave on a div and nested elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events, mouseenter

I want to display a toolbar if the mouse is over a div or any of the `div`'s nested elements. But the following solution with jQuery 1.7 only works if the mouse is over the `div` directly what is only possible if I add a `padding` to the `item` css class.

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .toolbar { display: none; }
    .item { padding: 1px; } /* doesn't work without padding! */
  </style>
  <title>Demo</title>
</head>

    <body>

  <div class="section">
    <div class="item">
      <p class="toolbar">TOOLS</p>
      <p>content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <p class="toolbar">TOOLS</p>
      <p>content</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(".section").on(
      "mouseenter",
      ".item",
      function(event) {

        $(event.target).children('.toolbar')
          .show(100);
      }
    )

    $(".section").on(
      "mouseleave",
      ".item",
      function(event) {
        $(event.target).children('.toolbar').hide();
      }
    )      
  </script>

</body>
```

A padding of 1px wouldn't be so bad, but it leads to bigger padding at the top and bottom and this workaround doesn't work properly - especially if the mouse enters from the left or right side.

How can I handle `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events without the padding trick?

Comment: I know @ManseUK's posted the correct answer, but I just wanted to add a quick note about the padding trick. This worked (most of the time) because adding padding stopped the [margins collapsing](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#collapsing-margins), so the events could be triggered on `.item` (where `event.target` was obviously what you wanted) as well as on the `p`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the `event.target` is not the div - changing to `$(this)` fixes the problem -> http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/StUvz/

Comment: `$('body')` **is** a valid selector, `$(document.body)` might simply be a bit faster though)

Comment: `$("body")` was a simplification in my example, I changed it to `.section` what is the class of a surrounding `div`.

Comment: @deamon OK - the other thing i changes was `$(this)` instead of `$(event.target)` -> http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Comment: @DidierG. ok - my fault - i changed 2 things at the same time and assumed it was that which resolved the problem !

Answer (score 2):

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smacky311/HZV8B/4/) I created works fine without padding.  Maybe you just need to tweak something small (like a width inherited in the CSS chain).

If that doesn't answer it for you, give us a fiddle that reproduces the problem so we can modify it for you.

Answer (score 0):

This one work without the padding, too http://jsfiddle.net/rkpVW/ you can directly do a on(".item") i think it's the easiest solution for binding elements.

Edit : http://jsfiddle.net/rkpVW/1/ using live for dynamic content

Comment: Using `$(".item")` directly wouldn't work when html is injected dynamically (what will happen in my case).

Comment: use the live function for that or delegate

Comment: I update the fiddle with dynamic insert and using live function http://jsfiddle.net/rkpVW/1/

Comment: `live()` is deprecated in jQuery 1.7.

Comment: Oh sorry about that haven't see that they deprecated the whole event handler, we have switch to 1.7 yet forget my answer then ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using `$(event.currentTarget)` will clear up the issue and will behave the same as `$(this)` only better as it will continue to work in situations where `this` is something else:

```
init: function()
{
    $("button").on("mouseenter", this.proxy(function(event)
    {
        this.classMethod();

        console.log( event.currentTarget );
    }) );
}
```

As you can see, `event.currentTarget` *is* `this`:

```
$("button").on("mouseenter", function(event)
{
    console.log( event.currentTarget === this );
});
```